# Youtube analytics API return incomplete data

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've been using youtube analytics API to fetch different reports, but since some days ago the api is not returning complete data, but only until 3 days before the current date.

The following is a request for video views report *f**rom 2020-04-20 until 2020-04-28***, but the response returns data only until ***2020-04-25***, but I can see in my channel that we have video views in the dates ***2020-04-26 and 2020-04-27***.

```
  'https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?dimensions=day%2CinsightTrafficSourceType&endDate=2020-04-28&filters=video%3D%3DoQqVWPfSfe8&ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&metrics=views%2CestimatedMinutesWatched&sort=day%2C-views&startDate=2020-04-20&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Response:

```
{
  "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
  "columnHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "day",
      "columnType": "DIMENSION",
      "dataType": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "insightTrafficSourceType",
      "columnType": "DIMENSION",
      "dataType": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "views",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "name": "estimatedMinutesWatched",
      "columnType": "METRIC",
      "dataType": "INTEGER"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "2020-04-20",
      "ADVERTISING",
      23429,
      12417
    ],
    [
      "2020-04-20",
      "NO_LINK_OTHER",
      31,
      5
    ],
    [
      "2020-04-20",
      "EXT_URL",
      5,
      0
    ],
    [
      "2020-04-21",
      "ADVERTISING",
      46469,
      24522
    ],
    [
      "2020-04-21",
      "NO_LINK_OTHER",
      54,
      9
    ],
    [
      "2020-04-21",
      "EXT_URL",
      5,
      1
    ],
    [
      "2020-04-22",
      "ADVERTISING",
      40020,
      21132
    ],
    [
      "2020-04-22",
      "NO_LINK_OTHER",
      43,
      9
    ],
    [
      "2020-04-22",
      "EXT_URL",
      7,
      2
    ],
    [
      "2020-04-23",
      "ADVERTISING",
      22944,
      12127
    ],
    [
      "2020-04-23",
      "NO_LINK_OTHER",
      32,
      6
    ],
    [
      "2020-04-23",
      "EXT_URL",
      3,
      0
    ],
    [
      "2020-04-24",
      "ADVERTISING",
      8549,
      4524
    ],
    [
      "2020-04-24",
      "NO_LINK_OTHER",
      42,
      9
    ],
    [
      "2020-04-24",
      "EXT_URL",
      7,
      3
    ],
    [
      "2020-04-25",
      "ADVERTISING",
      820,
      432
    ],
    [
      "2020-04-25",
      "NO_LINK_OTHER",
      30,
      3
    ],
    [
      "2020-04-25",
      "EXT_URL",
      8,
      1
    ]
  ]
}
```

Has something changed in the API? any new restrictions?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Some dimensions have been deprecated and removed as of the 15th of April, maybe this is the cause, see: [https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/dimensions#day](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/dimensions#day)

Comment: I don't think so because I'm using the day dimension and that one is not marked as deprecated. Thanks